# Constructor invocation returned null: what to do?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have code which looks like:

```
private static DirectiveNode CreateInstance(Type nodeType, DirectiveInfo info) {
    var ctor = nodeType.GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(DirectiveInfo) });

    if(ctor == null) {
        throw new MissingMethodException(nodeType.FullName, "ctor");
    }

    var node = ctor.Invoke(new[] { info }) as DirectiveNode;

    if(node == null) {
        // ???;
    }

    return node;
}
```

I am looking for what to do (e.g. what type of exception to throw) when the `Invoke` method returns something which isn't a `DirectiveNode` or when it returns `null` (indicated by `// ???` above).

(By the method's contract, `nodeType` will always describe a subclass of `DirectiveNode`.)

I am not sure when calling a constructor would return `null`, so I am not sure if I should handle anything at all, but I still want to be on the safe side and throw an exception if something goes wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to ensure that `nodeType` is a `DirectiveNode`:

```
if (!typeof(DirectiveNode).IsAssignableFrom(nodeType))
    throw new ArgumentException("The specified node type is not a 'DirectiveNode'");
```

Also, you can (should) use [`Activator.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx) instead of manually finding the `ConstructorInfo` and invoking it. It's cleaner, more expressive, and more maintainable.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know about `Activator.CreateInstance`.  Thanks.  By my contract I'm sure only a `DirectiveNode` subclass is sent to the function, so that wasn't the issue.  Anyway, thanks.  =]

Comment: Are you stopping the debugger and checking? Just because it seems impossible doesn't mean it is impossible.

Comment: The `as` never actually did return `null`.  I was asking if I try to should do anything if it did, because it looks like an impossible condition.

Comment: @strager: It could return `null` only if the argument is an invalid node type. To answer the question, yes you absolutely should check this condition and throw an `ArgumentException` if it's violated.